# How can I show the spinner/Indicator on tableView Loading cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

hello I have seen in some apps which shows spinner or activity indicator on a tableview cell which hasn't filled up with a value when user search something. Its hard to explain but it was like if I type something in the search bar,results starting to pops up on the tableview according to the keywords I type and spinner starts moving on the cells. if first two values comes fast it shows the spinner on the third cell, as long as values starting to fill up the cells,spinner goes to next cell which is empty. How can I have this effect. here is my code of searching Cities and countries

```
class CountryTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var delegate : CountryTableViewControllerDelegate! = nil
    var dict = NSDictionary()
    var filteredKeys = [String]()

    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

    var newTableData = [String]()

    var departureOrArrivalSegue:Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.resultSearchController = ({

            let controller  = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
            self.definesPresentationContext = true
            return controller


        })()

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if (self.resultSearchController.active) {

            return self.filteredKeys.count
        } else {

            return dict.count
        }

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CountryTableViewCell

        if(self.resultSearchController.active){

           // let key = self.filteredKeys[indexPath.row]

            //let dictionary = self.dict[key] as! NSDictionary






                let cityName = (((self.dict["\(indexPath.row)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Country"] as?NSDictionary)!["city_name"] as?NSString)

               let stateName  = (((self.dict["\(indexPath.row)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Country"] as? NSDictionary)!["state_name"] as? NSString)

                 let shortName  = (((self.dict["\(indexPath.row)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Country"] as? NSDictionary)!["short_country_name"] as? NSString)


            if (cityName !== "-" || shortName !== "-"){
                cell.stateNameLabel.text = stateName as? String
                cell.cityNameLabel.text = cityName as? String
                 cell.shortNameLabel.text = shortName as? String

            }

                      return cell

        }else{



            if let cityName = (((self.dict["\(indexPath.row)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Country"] as?NSDictionary)!["city_name"] as?NSString){
            cell.cityNameLabel.text = cityName as String
                }
            return cell
        }



    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let id = Int((((dict["\(indexPath.item)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Country"] as?NSDictionary)!["id"] as?NSString)! as String)

        let cityName = (((dict["\(indexPath.item)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Country"] as?NSDictionary)!["city_name"] as?NSString)! as String

        let countryShortName = (((dict["\(indexPath.item)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Country"] as?NSDictionary)!["short_country_name"] as?NSString)! as String

         delegate.country(id!,cityName: cityName, countryShortName: countryShortName,departureOrArrivalSegue: departureOrArrivalSegue!)

        self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)



    }



    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated);
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillDisappear(animated);
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

         self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }




    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchWord = searchController.searchBar.text!
        getCountriesNamesFromServer(searchWord)
    }



    func getCountriesNamesFromServer(searchWord:String) {
        let url:String = "localhost"
        let params = ["keyword":searchWord]

        ServerRequest.postToServer(url, params: params) { result, error in
            if let result = result {
                print(result)

                self.dict = result

                self.filteredKeys.removeAll()

                for (key, value) in self.dict {
                    let valueContainsCity: Bool = (((value as? NSDictionary)?["Country"] as? NSDictionary)?["city_name"] as? String)?.uppercaseString.containsString(searchWord.uppercaseString) ?? false

                    let valueContainsCountry: Bool = (((value as? NSDictionary)?["Country"] as? NSDictionary)?["country_name"] as? String)?.uppercaseString.containsString(searchWord.uppercaseString) ?? false

                    if valueContainsCity || valueContainsCountry {
                        self.filteredKeys.append(key as! String)
                    }
                }
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
}
}
```

This is the one of the app which has effect like this which I need

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What I've done is add a subView programmatically, so the main table is in the background, and the spinner is centralized.  This example is actually in Objective-C, but you get the idea.  It's in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]    initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
self.spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
self.spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80);
self.spinner.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2,    self.view.bounds.size.height / 2);
[self.view addSubview:self.spinner];
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends exactly what the effect you're looking for is, but you can add a view with the spinner as a subview (so you can position it centrally) as the table view footer.

Comment: sorry I do not get it. you are saying I should create a uiview and on top of uiview I should have a spinner and then position it on the cells? let me send you the app screenshot

Comment: No, as the table footer, not on any cell

Comment: okay could you please check the screenshot. I have just updated the question